# how to find which database file (.dat) is used for a given table in derbydb?

Tags: derby

in derbydb under seg0/ folder there are many database files with .dat extension, like:

```
c1c1ba61.dat
c1c1ba71.dat
c1c1ba80.dat
c1c1ba91.dat
c1c1baa1.dat
c1c1bab1.dat
c1c1bac0.dat
c1c1bad1.dat
c1c1bae0.dat
```

how to find which file is used for which table in that DB?

Answer (score 0):

Each file name is named according to its "conglomerate ID", and the relationship between the conglomerate ID and the table name is stored in the Derby system catalogs, so you can query those catalogs to figure this out.

I [wrote this up some time ago](http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2009/09/whats-in-those-files-in-my-derby-db.html), and I believe it still works. Quoting from that doc:

> if you're wondering which files are used by table EMPLOYEES:

```
 select c.conglomeratenumber, c.isindex, t.tablename 
        from sys.sysconglomerates c, 
             sys.systables t 
       where c.tableid=t.tableid 
         and t.tablename='EMPLOYEES';
```

You might also find the [SPACE_TABLE diagnostic function](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsyscsdiagspacetable.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Building on other answers, a complete solution could show you which conglomerate goes with which database object name.

in IJ or however you connect to derby, create a function to convert to hex

```
create function to_hex(inputInt integer)
returns varchar(255)
parameter style JAVA
no sql language JAVA
external name 'java.lang.Integer.toHexString'
```

Then run a query using the function to help show the name mapping

```
select 'c' || to_hex(c.conglomeratenumber)||'.dat', c.isindex, t.tablename 
    from sys.sysconglomerates c, 
         sys.systables t 
   where c.tableid=t.tableid
```